# Which one-sample statistical test for ordinal variables?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, image-processing

I have one group of <25 subjects and multiple evaluation scores:

New images of every patients has been rated by a radiologist compared to old images (1 to 5 with 1 Markedly worse, 3 similar and 5 Markedly better)
I don't have the score for the old images only the new ones that have been compared with the old images. I am confused how to do any statistical test?
I only know that it will be a non-parametric test: **maybe wilcox test?**

Something like that for every variable :

```
wilcox.test(tab$variable1,mu=4,alternative = "two.sided",conf.int = T)
```

?

Answer (score 1):

**Comments:**

It seems unlikely that you will find persuasive evidence
about the improvement of patients based on such a small sample.

Suppose you have $n = 21$ ordinal values denoted $1$ through $5.$
From the bit of R code you show, I assume you want to test the
null hypothesis that the mean or median is 4 against the two-sided
alternative. It is not clear to me exactly what conclusions you
would like to draw from your data, why you have chosen $4$ instead of $3$ as the null value, or why you have chosen a two-sided
alternative. [In my simulated data, with six patients possibly worse, nine possibly better, and six relatively unchanged, there seems not much to discuss.]

Consider the data I have simulated
in R below:

```
set.seed(2021)
x = sample(1:5, 21, rep=T, p=c(1,1,2,3,3))
table(x)
x
1 2 3 4 5 
2 4 6 5 4
```

Especially for sample sizes as small as $n = 21,$ the
one-sample Wilcoxon (signed-rank) test does not work
well if there are many ties in the data or if relatively many values
are at the value (here $4)$ specified in the null hypothesis.

```
wilcox.test(x, mu=4, sim=T)

        Wilcoxon signed rank test 
        with continuity correction

data:  x
V = 22, p-value = 0.0153
alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to 4

Warning messages:
1: In wilcox.test.default(x, mu = 4, sim = T) :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
2: In wilcox.test.default(x, mu = 4, sim = T) :
  cannot compute exact p-value with zeroes
```

Even so, the *approximate* P-value of about $0.014 < 0.05 = 5\%$
may suggest that the population from which your observations were
taken is not centered at $4.$

A one-sided sign test would reject at the 5% level. The logic
is that you have $21-5 = 16$ observations that are not $4$ and
among those only $4$ exceed score $4.$ The P-value of the sign test
is the probability $0.0384 < 0.5 = 5\%$ of getting $4$ or fewer scores above $4$ under
the assumption that scores above and below $4$ are equally likely.

```
pbinom(4, 16, .5)
[1] 0.03840637
```

The core procedures in R do not include a sign test, but Minitab does sign tests. For my hypothetical data the output is shown below.

```
Sign Test for Median: x 

Sign test of median =  4.000 versus < 4.000

    N  Below  Equal  Above       P  Median
x  21     12      5      4  0.0384   3.000
```

If my small dataset were real, I would say there is some evidence,
but weak evidence that the new x-rays look better. However, I don't
believe any choices about medical practice should be based on fewer
than two dozen subjects.

---

*Note:* If you assume your data are numerical instead of ordinal, and
pretend that scores are somehow nearly normal, then a test of $H_0:\mu=4$ vs. $H_a: \mu \ne 4$ rejects below the 5% level. I mention this test (pretty much based on fantasy) just so you will know I thought of it.

```
t.test(x, mu=4)$p.val
[1] 0.01185307
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Would you think it's better to use H0:m≤m0 : wilcox.test(tab$variable1,mu=3,alternative = "greater",conf.int = T)? to show basically that the score is significantly higher than 3 (which means it's at least slightly better to use the new images than the old ones?); Also i was wondering, I have 5 variables, should I do some correction for multiple comparisons to know if it's really significant?

Comment: Need to correct for multiple comparisons strongest for repeated uses of the same data. (Using data once for one-way ANOVA with 5 level, then again for ${5\choose 2}=10$ paired comparisons is frequent example.) What are your five variables, and is it reasonable to view them as independent? Or are they just slightly different ways to measure the same thing? // Having much less familiarity than you with the actual situation, I'm not sure about null value or one vs. two sided. Based on what I think I know, right-sided alternative with null value 3 seems reasonable.

Comment: However, for my fake data right-sided Wilcoxon SR test with null 3 results in non-signif P value and several lines of warning messages. Hardly a conclusive result. In R, code `wilcox.test(x, mu=3, alt="g")$p.val` returns $0.1975088.$ Might work better for your real data.

Comment: Thank you. I think i will stick with one sided (higher), bc I try to answer :  “Are qualitative scores significantly higher from a ‘neutral’ score of 3 (trying to determine if the median of the evaluation score of the new images is greater than 3, meaning better than the old images).All 5 variables are very correlated. For example if " image resolution"(variable 1) is better then we will be able to see better the "lesions" (variable 2) in the brain. I used Bonferroni correction for multiple comparisons (pvalue.adj<-p.adjust(pvalue.res,method = "bonferroni",n=5). Am I right ?